# Batch file is not getting completely executed.

Tags: jenkins

We are trying to make a Jenkins job where we will deploy our Angular app to Tomcat's webapps folder.

Our Jenkins is running on CentOS and dev server is on Windows.

We executing the following shell script in Jenkins build step.

`sshpass -p "password" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no username@host "D:\Ratikanta\temp.bat"`

Our batch file content is following.

`d: && cd Ratikanta && svn checkout http://192.168.1.5/svn/KSP/trunk/kspweb/ && cd kspweb && npm i && npm run build && move ksp D:\Ratikanta\Tomcat7\webapps`

These are working fine when running the shell script(`sshpass -p ...`) from CentOS terminal but, when running from Jenkins job it is executing up to `npm i`. Other commands like `npm run build && move ksp D:\Ratikanta\Tomcat7\webapps` are not getting executed.

Please help. Did we miss something? Please suggest if there are any other way to achieve our goal.

Comment: check on window machine, does it have `npm` which already installed ?

Comment: Yes @ThanhNguyenVan npm version 5.6.0